# Please help edit this question so it can be reopened

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/106810/32436) is about getting educational disability accommodations in the UK.

Come on, people.  This is an area Academia SE needs to get stronger in.  We have pretty good coverage about Section 504 in the US.  This question is giving us an opportunity to start expanding our collection of know-how about how this is handled in other countries.

Please help edit the question so it can be reopened.

(Inexplicably, the reopen number is at zero, even though I voted to reopen.)

Comment: Your reopen vote "aged away" because it got three "Leave Closed" votes in the review queue and didn't get any more reopen votes for 4 days. See the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @ff524 - Ah, thanks for explaining.

Comment: It has been reopened.

Comment: @NateEldredge - Yes.  I'm not sure what to do here.  I hesitated to accept the existing answer because it argued for non-mod reopening (which didn't work, and so I raised a flag on the question after the OP made some more helpful edits).

Answer (score 4):

I've edited the question. I believe the problems were twofold: (1) the question was university-specific, and (2) too much was made of the housing situation. There's not much I can do about problem (1), but I did what I could about (2).

However, I think that even though a specific university is mentioned, other universities probably have special arrangements that are similar.

As a diamond mod, I can't cast a vote to reopen, since it will work unilaterally. However, I agree with the view we need to do more, and would support its reopening.

Comment: With all respect, aeismail, I think the moderators should go ahead and reopen the question.